# xap not refreshed in Chrome

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome, xap

I've just updated my xap application, the changes are reflected as expected in IE. However, in Chrome, I can see it is still the old design. 
In VS2010 I've tried recompiling after unticking 'Reduce XAP size by using application library caching' but no changes
I'm not sure what other information I should provide to get help - feel free to ask questions!
Thanks

EDIT: If I use the incognito mode in Chrome, the xap displayed is the latest version, so it clearly seems to be a problem in Chrome. However the users of my website can't know that, how can I circumvent the bug? I'm using Chrome 10.0.0.648

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least this solution works with Firefox.

Add an empty parameter (`?refresh` in this case) to the source of the xap-file on the page with `object` tag and silverlight application:

```
<object id="slPlugin" name="SilverlightApplication" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApp.xap?refresh"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as your application is versioned you can use the following solution which force the refresh as the url changes with the version number :

```
var versionNumber = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();

<object data=\"data:application/x-silverlight-2,\" type=\"application/x-silverlight-2\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" id=\"slobj\">
<param name=\"source\" value=\"ClientBin/Application.xap?" + versionNumber + "\"/>
```